# Deploying Application Manifest

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, installation, deployment, intune

I am attempting to deploy an application called TempWorks Enterprise with Microsoft Endpoint Manager (Intune). The application is packaged as an application manifest (.application) instead of an EXE or MSI. I have tried to wrap this application as a Win32 and deploy it with Intune but it doesn't work. Are there any other methods you can think of to silently install this application through Intune? Below is the link where you can find this application.

https://enterprise.tempworks.com/

If you right-click on the "Start Application" link and you select "Save Link As", you will see that the package is an application manifest which is described at this link here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sbscs/application-manifests